# PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgis

I followed the setup [link](http://dazuma.github.io/activerecord-postgis-adapter/rdoc/Documentation_rdoc.html) want to integrate `PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter` into my project, my Rails project has installed postgis already by [postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach](http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html)

I followed those steps to `Working With Spatial Data`

And launch Rails console

```
c = Spatial.new()

c.lonlat = 'POINT(-122,48)'

2.1.0 :004 > c
+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
| id | lonlat | created_at | updated_at | shap1 | shp2 | path | lon | lat |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
|    |        |            |            |       |      |      |     |     |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
```

database.yml

```
 16 #
 17 development:
 18   adapter: postgis
 19   encoding: unicode
 20   database: goodshot_development
 21   schema_search_path: public,postgis
```

migration file

```
class CreateSpatials < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spatials do |t|
      t.column :shap1, :geometry
      t.geometry :shp2
      t.line_string :path, :srid => 3785
      t.point :lonlat, :geographic => true
      t.point :lon
      t.point :lat
      t.index :lonlat, :spatial => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [link](http://dazuma.github.io/activerecord-postgis-adapter/rdoc/Documentation_rdoc.html) you provided shows a very similar example of what *not* to do, which is what you did.

That is, to provide invalid [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text):

```
record.lonlat = 'POINT(-122, 47)'
```

Which fails to parse, and silently sets the value to nil. (Valid WKT looks like `POINT(-122 47)`).

The link describes a few alternative ways to construct a geometry, such as:

```
factory.point(-122, 47)
```

Comment: I updated the activerecord-postgis-adapter README to fix the incorrect documentation (removed the comma).